# Django pre-save

Tags: python, django

I'm working on my first project with Django ,it's a personal blog

the story model has 'beginning' filed that is first 100 characters of the story itself

I want to create beginning with pre_save but I got error always : in admin section when I add a story and leave the beginning blank ,Django say 'this field is required'!!

this works very good in another file

here is the code :

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

from my_blog_tags.models import Tag


# Create your models here.

class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    story = models.TextField()
    beginning = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "story"
        verbose_name_plural = "stories"


def story_pre_save(sender, instance: Story, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.beginning:
        story = str(instance.story)
        instance.beginning = story[:100]


pre_save.connect(story_pre_save, sender=Story)
```

Screenshot from admin section:

[image: 1]

Comment: Please show the full traceback. I would strongly advise *not* to use signals. Signals are an antipattern: https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/ especially for this. You here do not need a `beginning` field in the first place I think, this is basically just a property.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It has value as its own field as it could be manually set to something else. I agree that you shouldn't use signals unless you need to hook into 3rd party apps' behaviour.

Comment: @schwobaseggl: yes I agree that we can use this if a user can define a beginning themselves, but if it is always the "sliced" version of `.story`, then this should not be stored in the database. But you are right that a user could define a different beginning.

Comment: Then again, a `get_beginning` method à la `return self.beginning or self.story[:100]` would be simpler than venturing into this wilderness :-) especially if you ever want to change the default beginning logic.

Comment: do you mean it's better add a method in ModelManger to return first 100 characters of story field ?

Comment: @Mohammadjavad: yes. Signals are not very reliable: some ORM calls like `.bulk_create(..)` and `.update(..)` circumvent the signals, so that means that there are ways to create/update stories, without the `.beginning` getting updated accordingly. Even if that would work, it makes it less clear what exactly happens when you save a model object. Only in rare circumstances signals are useful.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem if it's not a good way ,how I can do this in another way : Tag model has `title` and `in_url` fields ,`in_url'`is the same as title but with `replace(' ','-')` in the pre_save function

Comment: @Mohammadjavad: it looks like you are making your own `slugify` with the `replace` part (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify). I would advise to use `slugify` instead. You better override the `def save()` method and slugify there, or you set it in the view. You can also make use of an [**`AutoSlugField`**](https://django-autoslug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) of `django-autoslug` to simply specify what should be slugified, and then you do not have to care about this yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you get originates from the fact that `beginning` is a *required* field. You can allow a form item to be blank with [**`blank=True`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#blank) in the corresponding model field:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    # …
    beginning = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

I would also advise *not* to use a signals to set the `beginning` field if it is left blank. [Signals are an antipattern](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/). They are useful if you have models in another application, but if you have control over the model, it is not a good idea to work with signals.

A more elegant way to solve this might be the one advised by [@schwobaseggl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65382351/django-pre-save/65382454#comment115592176_65382351), where you have a property that either takes the beginning or slices the story, so:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    
    def get_beginning(self):
        return self.beginning or self.story[:100]
```

You can use this in a template with `{{ mystory.get_beginning }}`. If you do not specify a `.beginning` yourself, and you later update the `.story`, then the `get_beginning` will automatically return an updated sliced version.

Comment: he want's to save first 100 characters of story field in beginning field. overriding save method should be good

Comment: @RezaGH: a problem with that is that if you later alter the `story`, then that will no longer "update". It would also make the database larger, since now it basically copies the first 100 characters in the `beginning`, this also slows down a query, because it requires more "bandwidth" to return the data from the database. So it is an *duplicate data*-antipattern

Comment: so, we no longer need beginning field itself?

Comment: @RezaGH: no we do. You have a `beginning` field where you can enter a *different* beginning if necessary. The point is that we have both fields, but that we perform the logic to either select the `self.beginning` or the `self.story[:100]` at runtime. So that means if you later alter `self.beginning` for a different beginning, `self.get_beginning()` will then return that beginning, and no longer the sliced variant of the story.

Comment: @RezaGH: this allows, as [schwobaseggl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65382351/django-pre-save/65382454#comment115592098_65382351) says, to automatically use the sliced story, or specify a custom-made beginning.

Comment: Thank for your help and explanation <3

Answer (score 1):

There is not need to use singles you can override `save` method. To do this for you.
you just have to do something like this

```
    class Story(models.Model):
        beginning = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.beginning = self.story[0:100]
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It will automatically save the first 100 characters of your story.